# Getting branch name from Gitlab payload - Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I am using parameterized job in Jenkins where the I send the GIT-REPO as a parameter, and I define this parameter in Gitlab repository webhook.
For example, if I created the Jenkins job with name 'test', then i add the following hook in the Gitlab repository:

```
http://jenkins-server/job/test/buildWithParameters?GITREPO=git@gitlab.com/test-repo.git&SOMEOTHERPARAMETER=somevalue
```

Now, I want to build the branch which triggers the hook.
How can I do that?
Gitlab Hook Plugin might not work as I using a single parameterized job.

Answer (score 2):

GitLab invokes the webhook URL with a JSON payload in the request body that carries a lot of information about the GitLab event that led to the webhook invocation. For example, the [GitLab webhook **push event** payload](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#push-events) carries the following information in it that includes repo name (notice the "**repository**" field):

```
{
  "object_kind": "push",
  "before": "95790bf891e76fee5e1747ab589903a6a1f80f22",
  "after": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "checkout_sha": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
  "user_id": 4,
  "user_name": "John Smith",
  "user_username": "jsmith",
  "user_email": "john@example.com",
  "user_avatar": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/d4c74594d841139328695756648b6bd6?s=8://s.gravatar.com/avatar/d4c74594d841139328695756648b6bd6?s=80",
  "project_id": 15,
  "project":{
    "id": 15,
    "name":"Diaspora",
    "description":"",
    "web_url":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora",
    "avatar_url":null,
    "git_ssh_url":"git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "git_http_url":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora.git",
    "namespace":"Mike",
    "visibility_level":0,
    "path_with_namespace":"mike/diaspora",
    "default_branch":"master",
    "homepage":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora",
    "url":"git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "ssh_url":"git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "http_url":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora.git"
  },
  "repository":{
    "name": "Diaspora",
    "url": "git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "description": "",
    "homepage": "http://example.com/mike/diaspora",
    "git_http_url":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora.git",
    "git_ssh_url":"git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "visibility_level":0
  },
  "commits": [
    {
      "id": "b6568db1bc1dcd7f8b4d5a946b0b91f9dacd7327",
      "message": "Update Catalan translation to e38cb41.",
      "timestamp": "2011-12-12T14:27:31+02:00",
      "url": "http://example.com/mike/diaspora/commit/b6568db1bc1dcd7f8b4d5a946b0b91f9dacd7327",
      "author": {
        "name": "Jordi Mallach",
        "email": "jordi@softcatala.org"
      },
      "added": ["CHANGELOG"],
      "modified": ["app/controller/application.rb"],
      "removed": []
    },
    {
      "id": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
      "message": "fixed readme",
      "timestamp": "2012-01-03T23:36:29+02:00",
      "url": "http://example.com/mike/diaspora/commit/da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
      "author": {
        "name": "GitLab dev user",
        "email": "gitlabdev@dv6700.(none)"
      },
      "added": ["CHANGELOG"],
      "modified": ["app/controller/application.rb"],
      "removed": []
    }
  ],
  "total_commits_count": 4
}
```

So, you need not add any query parameter (GIT-REPO or any other) to your webhook URL. And whether or not your Jenkins job is parameterised,  the [Jenkins GitLab plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin) makes this webhook payload information available in the [Jenkins Global Variable](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference) **env**. The [available **env** variables](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables) are as follows and they do include repository information:

```
gitlabBranch
gitlabSourceBranch
gitlabActionType
gitlabUserName
gitlabUserEmail
gitlabSourceRepoHomepage
gitlabSourceRepoName
gitlabSourceNamespace
gitlabSourceRepoURL
gitlabSourceRepoSshUrl
gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl
gitlabMergeRequestTitle
gitlabMergeRequestDescription
gitlabMergeRequestId
gitlabMergeRequestIid
gitlabMergeRequestState
gitlabMergedByUser
gitlabMergeRequestAssignee
gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit
gitlabMergeRequestTargetProjectId
gitlabTargetBranch
gitlabTargetRepoName
gitlabTargetNamespace
gitlabTargetRepoSshUrl
gitlabTargetRepoHttpUrl
gitlabBefore
gitlabAfter
gitlabTriggerPhrase
```

Just as you would read Jenkins job parameters from [Jenkins Global Variable](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference) **params** in your job pipeline script, you could read webhook payload fields from [Jenkins Global Variable](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference) **env**:

```
params.MY_PARAM_NAME
env.gitlabSourceRepoURL
```

Hope, the above information helps solve your problem.

Comment: I'm using declarative pipeline job with parameters.(like project_name: git_branch, etc..). in GitLab webhook URL, I have a use case to pass the branch name dynamically.   is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins project:

Define the string parameter as gitlabTargetBranch and you can update this variable in SCM with */$gitlabTargetBranch